# Probability of choosing from Box II?

Tags: probability

An experiment consists of first drawing a ball from box 1 (which contains 1 red and 2 blue), noting the color, and placing the ball in box 2 (which initially contained 2 red and 2 blue). Next a ball is drawn from box 2 and color is noted. If it is known that both a red and a blue ball were drawn, what is the probability that the red ball came from box 2?

I tackled this question by multiplying (2/3) by (2/5). I chose to do this because of the chances first taking blue from the first box then red from the second box. However, it says it's wrong. Can someone help me please?

Comment: Use Bayes' Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

What you calculated is the probability of first drawing a blue ball from box 1 and then drawing a red ball from box 2 after placing the blue ball from box 1 in box 2, which we can write as $P(B1+R2)$. So, you found that:

$$P(B1+R2)=\frac{2}{3}\cdot \frac{2}{5}$$

However, what you need to calculate is the *conditional* probability of this to have happened *given* that one blue and one red ball was drawn, which we can write as $P(B1+R2|B+R)$.

To find this conditional probability, first also calculate the probability of first drawing a red ball from box 1, putting this in box 2, and then drawing a blue ball from box 2. This will be $P(R1+B2)$:

$$P(R1+B2)=\frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{2}{5}$$

Add up those two probabilities and you get the probability that one blue and one red ball was drawn:

$$P(B+R)=P(B1+R2)+P(R1+B2)$$

and now you can get the asked for conditional probability as follows:

$$P(B1+R2|B+R)=\frac{P(B1+R2)}{P(B+R)}$$

Answer (score 0):

We are given that we selected a blue and red ball. So if we find that the blue ball was from box one then we are guaranteed that a red will be from box two. So the probability is the same as the probability of selecting a blue ball initially, $$p=\frac{2}{3}$$

This can alternatively by found by using Bayes' Theorem:

$$\begin{align*}
P(\text{R from box 2} | \text{R and B})
&=\frac{P(\text{R from box 2} \cap \text{R and B})}{P(\text{R and B)}}\\\\
&=\frac{\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{2}{5}}{\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{2}{5}+\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{2}{5}}\\\\
&=\frac{2}{3}
\end{align*}$$